# Why container of Lambda with Sequelize after conn. error to RDS can't reconnect until new container is being created?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

There is connection:

`Lambda` with `sequelize` -- `RDS` with `Aurora DB` instance

According to advices from `sequelize` github, all schemas and connection are defined outside `lambda` `handler` to provide persist and fast connection to `RDS`.

Sometimes `lambda` returns `sequelize` connection error and then it's impossible for `lambda` to reach `RDS` until it's new container is being created (e.g. after deploy). It looks like the access to `RDS` for particular `lambda` container is blocked.

Does anyone know what may be the reason of that behaviour?

Error:

```
"name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
            "parent": {
                "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
                "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
                "syscall": "connect",
                "fatal": true
            },
```

Comment: Just to confirm, it works some of the time, right?

Comment: Yes, changing parameter `pool.minConenctions` to 1 temporarily solved the issue. It has not crash yet.